# C# Regex take name from string

Tags: c#, regex, string

Im getting strings somethink like this

```
"????log L 07/13/2012 - 23:59:21: \"Baobi<1><STEAM_ID_PENDING><>\" connected, address \"72.539.185.197:27005\"\n\0"
```

I had this method but sometimes its very buggy

```
 if (Data.EndsWith("\"")) Data = Data.Substring(0, Data.Length - 1);
                int start = Data.IndexOf("\"");
                int end = Data.IndexOf("<");
                var val = Data.Substring(start + 1, end - 1 - start);
                return val;
```

Please provides some good regex to get `Baobi` from here

Comment: Your current solution looks perfectly right to me. Why do you want a regex?

Comment: Good point, @Gene.  OP: If you show some examples of what strings aren't working with your current code, we can be sure to have the regex take care of that.

Comment: I dont know string where occured error. Only i know error message from Windows Server Event viewer

Comment: Can't you see anything else about the error, e.g. to determine if Data was null or if an exception was thrown from Substring or IndexOf?  You might want to put a try/catch around it and throw or log a more descriptive message that includes the contents of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this should work:

```
return Regex.Match(Data, @"""(.+?)<").Groups[1].ToString();
```

If this is still buggy, please give examples of strings that are problematic, and the results (e.g. exception details or what string was actually returned).

Comment: Or similarly, `return Regex.Match(Data, @"""(.+?)<").Groups[1].ToString();`. That has the advantage of allowing for more characters there (such as numbers).